# Windchill REST API Get all WorkItems

Tags: rest, ptc-windchill

We want to create a list with tasks of all users by using the Windchill REST API.

We used the GET/WorkItems Endpoint to get the list.

```
Windchill/servlet/odata/v3/Workflow/WorkItems
```

It works fine for those tasks, who are associatet with the user who posts the request. But we need a list with workitems of all users. Is there any possibility to get a response for that need?

If it is not possible to get such a response, is it possible to do an expand on objects like a change Request, to get the ID of associatet WorkItems?